# Create event data source for this query

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to execute this query in cloudwatch lake.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    $EDS_ID 
WHERE
    eventsource = 'signin.amazonaws.com'  
    AND eventname = 'ConsoleLogin'  
    AND Element_at(additionaleventdata, 'MFAUsed' 
    ) = 'No'
```

But I am not able to create Event Data Source correctly. Because the relevant signin option is not available in the drop-down. Available "Data event type" are like S3, Lambda, etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as `cloudwatch lake`. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean CloudTrail Lake and creating Event data store.

You do not need to select the `Data Events` box. All you need to make it work is the `Management events`.

Leave all by default when creating Event data store,
and test the query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    e1490c52-11ee-44be-827e-2cefa50780ab
WHERE
    eventName='ConsoleLogin'
    AND eventsource='signin.amazonaws.com'
    AND Element_at(additionaleventdata, 'MFAUsed' 
    ) = 'No'
```

where `e1490c52-11ee-44be-827e-2cefa50780ab` is Event data store ID